# Gnuplot filled curves not showing properly

Tags: plot, gnuplot, figure

I am trying to plot a filled curve with Gnuplot. If I set the Y range to a large value, the filled curve is plotting just fine. However, when I use a small Y range, some part of the curve are not filling with colors.

```
set terminal postscript color size 3.25,3.25 font "Helvetica, 8"
set output "test.ps"
set key at screen 0.95,0.70 right bottom
set border lt 1 lc 0 lw 1
set lmargin at screen 0.25
set rmargin at screen 0.95
set tmargin at screen 0.675
set bmargin at screen 0.15
set xlabel "X"
set ylabel "Y"
set xr [-1:2]
set yr [0:160]
set format x "%2.1f"
set style fill transparent solid 0.4
plot "data" w filledcurve x1 lt 1 lw 0.1 lc rgb "red"
```

This figure is the one with large Y range which is just fine. [image]

This one is the figure with small Y range which is not plotting well. [image]

The data file is available here. https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1OIHLT2Mz4QGX3VKeZCGM_S4VjTO0FuOc?usp=sharing

Any comment or solution would be appreciated. Thank you all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No such problem in gnuplot version 5 (confirmed back to version 5.0 patchlevel 3).
Output from current 5.2.4 shown.
[image: output from gnuplot 5.2.4]

Comment: I see. Thanks for your help Ethan!